# Recreate ASPX Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm creating a tool that populates a call to a JavaScript function through C#. So the code pulls down the values to pass to the function from the database, and the ASPX page uses `Eval` to pull that data from the `Repeater` it's stored in. However, when I change those values, the calls to the JavaScript function are not adjusted to pull down those values again (despite the page reloading).

For example, here is the call to the JavaScript function:

```
SetupImg('<%# Eval("pID") %>', '<%# Eval("ratio") %>', '228', '400', '<%# Eval("xval") %>', '<%# Eval("yval") %>');
```

These calls to `Eval()` pull from a Repeater which is populated in the code with a `DataView` as its `DataSource` (pulled from a database). How can I have the ASPX recreated to get new values whenever the Save button is clicked in another modal (which causes PostBack)?

Comment: Sounds like your Repeater is not getting the updated DataView.  Did you set debug breakpoints to see what's happening?

Comment: The function that binds the data is only called if `IsPostBack` returns true. It seems like that's what is causing the binding issue.

Comment: If you would like to share the relevant code behind then we might be able to help, otherwise there isn't much to go on.